# How to trigger 404 for custom query var?

Tags: wp-query, 404-error, rewrite-rules

How can you trigger a 404 when using custom query vars? I've got re-write rules written for a custom query var, but if you were to request a URL for the query var that should technically be a 404 it returns a normal WP page, but no content, because nothing technically exists for the URL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an action specifically for this:

```
function my_parse_query( $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->get( 'my_custom_var' ) > 42 ) {
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'my_parse_query' );
```

That should load the 404.php template in your theme, if you have it. Otherwise, it will fall back to index.php.

This will also trigger a HTTP 404 status code.

For more information see [parse_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_query).

Answer (score 1):

Add a 404.php to your theme and look if it is called.

#### Sample 404.php

```
<!doctype>
<title>404</title>
<p>404 – Mwah!</p>
```

What is more important: the real HTTP headers, here the status code. You can see it with your browsers developer tools under **network**. Here is a screen shot for `http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/404` in Opera Dragonfly:

[image: screen shot]

[See full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23PFe.png)

If you still get a status code 200, look into the global variables `$wp` and `$wp_query`. They will tell you more details about the fetched resource.