# "Headers already sent" error triggered in "parse_query" action

Tags: 404-error, headers

I have this code registered to the "parse_query" action which attempts to trigger a 404 based on the availability of an API asset. My implementation is based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13163/43552) to another question.

```
public function throw404($query)
{
    if ($this->avorgApi->getPresentation($query->get("presentation_id"))) return;

    $query->set_404();
    $this->wp->call("status_header", 404);
}
```

(`$this->wp->call(...)` is just a simple wrapper object that allows me to stub out and spy on my calls to WordPress. It calls the `status_header` function just the same as if I had called it directly.)

The `throw404()` function is registered in the object's `__construct()` method, like so:

```
$this->wp->call("add_action", "parse_query", [$this, "throw404"]);
```

When the requested asset is missing and the 404 is triggered, I get the following error:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

I discovered that I can prevent the error by commenting out the second to last line in the function (`$query->set_404();`), but neither is the 404 thrown, which defeats the purpose.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You haven't shown where or how your throw404() function is called.

Comment: @PeterHvD I've added the call to the question. Could you take a look at it again?

Comment: What happens if you remove the wrapper object from the equation and call the status_header function directly within the same throw404 function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically, the problem was that I also had registered a URL rewrite that set `page_id` as a query var, which overrode the 404 and loaded the referenced page. I fixed this by adding this line to my `throw404()` function:

```
unset($query->query_vars["page_id"]);
```